# writing word macro -- how do I write a Find to locate the next Korean character on a line?

Tags: vba, find, ms-word, cjk

I'm trying to take a large file of Korean vocabulary and set it up to import smoothly into a flashcard program.  The format of the file is [Korean word/phrase] [English translation] [Korean sample sentence].  Example:

너무 피곤해서 Because I’m tired 너무 피곤해서 잤어요.

I can write a macro to look for the first English letter and replace the space before it with a tab.  I identified the first English letter by searching for the range [a-Z].  After that I want to locate the beginning of the sample sentence by searching for the next Korean character encountered, but **what is the range for Korean characters?**

I found a unicode FAQ on Korean characters which seemed to suggest that each character is really just a combination of individual letters, and in some kinds of programming can be treated as the separate letters, but I probably misunderstood.  The idea was that something like "식" is really the three letters "ㅅ" + "ㅣ" + "ㄱ".  So I tried a search on just the one letter "ㅅ" (which appears in tons of characters in my input file) and got no hits.  That sure had the potential to make things simple, but no dice.

Comment: Just a thought, as a workaround could you search for the first character following a space that is NOT in the range [a-Z]?

Comment: I totally tried that route, and it's not out of the question, but I ran into problems there, too.  First I was hitting punctuation, so I tried to exclude individual punctuation marks from my search.  The input file had tons of single quotes, though (see "I'm" in the example above), and while I was able to exclude other punctuation from the Find, I stayed up late last night trying to escape a single quote in the macro, and none of the different methods I tried (backslash, double backslash, use two single quotes, enclose the single quote in double quotes, etc.) worked.

Comment: You could use the `ASC` function to get the Unicode value of the character? See this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262678%28VS.60%29.aspx) Link

Comment: There are maybe 10,000+ Korean characters, because each one is made up of some combination of between two and four of the 24 basic letters, and the problem is that I don't know which character is the first one in the list and which is the last.  I could use ASC to find the Unicode of one character, but I don't know how to find the range.

Comment: Oh.  First character *following a space* that is not in the [a-Z] range.  If I can't get any info on the Korean character range, I'll try the space + non-a-Z character search.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, got it -- found the range here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_language_and_computers#Hangul_in_Unicode

The below code in my macro finds the next Korean character in a Word document:

```
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "[" & ChrW(44032) & "-" & ChrW(55203) & "]"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute
```